# Prevent forced image loading/overwriting

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am building a website and have done a WordPress installation on the hosting. It was working fine till I parked my domain name when I started getting an image forcibly loaded on my webpage. You can find it [here](http://lonehawkstudios.com). I want to prevent this forced image loading on my page. It also overwrites all the images on my page.

I've tried searching for an answer on this but unable to find. But here's the actual question:

1. Can I block all requests to securesignupoffers.org, from where the image is loaded?
   (or)
2. Can I block the image URL from loading?

I haven't used hotlinking on my website, so I'm sure that I'm not violating their terms of use. Note: I do not have access to the .htaccess file.